# Button click and performing other UI tasks

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, xcode6

When the user taps a button, I'd like to check if my username/password textbox is valid (contains text) and if not, draw a red x next to each box. If it's valid (user provided a username/password), then i'd like to perform a segue with identifier.

When I try this and click the button, everything freezes. If I do the validation and then wrap the ui updates in an async it doesn't lock up the button anymore visually (but I still can't click it). I'm sure i'm missing something fundamentally important to GCD but could someone help me? I feel like no matter what I try, everything locks up and my icons don't appear / form becomes frozen/unresponsive. Thanks!

```
 @IBAction func btnLoginTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    //Reset validation
    txtUsername.rightView = nil
    txtPassword.rightView = nil
    var isFormValid = true
    var errorImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: ("redx")))
    errorImageView.frame = CGRectMake(5, (view!.frame.size.height - 20) / 2, 20, 20)
    errorImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center

    if ((self.txtUsername.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()).utf16Count == 0) || (self.txtPassword.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()).utf16Count == 0)) {

        isFormValid = false

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            if (self.txtUsername.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()).utf16Count == 0) {
                self.txtUsername.rightView = errorImageView
                self.txtUsername.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
            }
            if (self.txtPassword.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()).utf16Count == 0) {
                self.txtPassword.rightView = errorImageView
                self.txtPassword.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always       
            }
        }
    }



    if (isFormValid) {
        ..do other stuff, potentially also a segue with identifier
     }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use GCD to update the UI here. Are you leaving anything out of the method you posted?

Comment: It seems as if something later on in the method's "freezing" the UI... Normally the UI would update at the end of the method, but since it's updating in the GCD block, it seems like you're "freezing" before the end of the method.

Comment: When you enter correct username/password is app able to navigate to next view controller? You don't need the isFormValid property. Define a else to invoke viewcontroller. Also remove the dispatch_async and add nslog to both if and else, then check if your application freezes.

Comment: (self.txtPassword.text.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()).utf16Count == 0)   this seems to be the problem, specifically it's a password field is there a chance this is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I determined (as users said) this had nothing to do with async or ui threads, it was because I tried to do this on a password field:

```
 txtPassword.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```

This seems to lockup the thread but does not throw an error, oddly enough.
I'll avoid this.